# Table move column position by click

Tags: html, css, html-table

Now there is a table with a fixed (position sticky) left column.

It is necessary to implement the behavior so that by clicking on the button another column is displayed and that both of these behaviors work.

Any idea how this can be implemented?
https://gyazo.com/76e95a989ec132d54156357796ba8e8e

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use margin, but in this case, switching by touching not working.

Comment: Hope it helps:

[Simple Swipe with Vanilla JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/simple-swipe-with-vanilla-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

```js
$(function () {
  let responsiveTable = $(".table-responsive");
  $('.plan-switcher-btn').on('click', () => {
    let scrollLeft = responsiveTable.scrollLeft();
    let maxScrollLeft = responsiveTable.prop("scrollWidth") - responsiveTable.prop("clientWidth");
    if(scrollLeft === 0){
      responsiveTable.scrollLeft(maxScrollLeft);
    } else {
      responsiveTable.scrollLeft(0);
    }
  })
});
```